# Android app crop photo

Tags: java, android, crop, photo

I have a question.
This is the code that my application already have and it works like this : **takes photo** >**crop** > **upload**.
I don't want to crop the photo .How can I do this? Just deleting the dispatchCropImageIntent method?

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onActivityResult");
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            File imageFile = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            if (imageFile.exists()) {
               dispatchCropImageIntent(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY_SELECT) {
            dispatchCropImageIntent(data.getData());
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICTURE_CROP) {
            String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/temporary_holder.jpg";
            setCurrentBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));
        } else if(requestCode == CAMERA_ACTIVITY_CODE){
            // Get path
            String path = data.getStringExtra(CustomCamera.OUT_PATH);

            // Read file
            byte[] imgData = AppFS.readFileFromPath(path);
            if (imgData != null) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgData , 0, imgData.length);
                // TODO: Do something with the image, it should be okay
                //((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else {
                Log.e("Main", "Data is null");
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

And :

```
private void dispatchCropImageIntent(Uri uri) {
    Intent cropImageIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropImageIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    cropImageIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    cropImageIntent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
    cropImageIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
    // retrieve data on return
    cropImageIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "/temporary_holder.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("io", ex.getMessage());
    }

    uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    cropImageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    startActivityForResult(cropImageIntent, REQUEST_PICTURE_CROP);
}
```

Comment: Just remove dispatchCropImageIntent() method and get that image path for future use

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly,you want to make your app working like this:   **takes photo > upload.** So, you need to replace **dispatchCropImageIntent()** with **setCurrentBitmap()** or **upload methond**.